# QField - creating new feature classes?

Tags: qfield

Is there any way QField can make a new feature class (shapefile, or whatever format) in program?  Or can it only load pre-existing ones?  My use case is extremely ad-hoc so I'd like the ability to create new FCs in program instead of having to plan it out more.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible.

But you could create a generic project with a point, line and polygon layer. Each layer with fields called field1, field2 etc. You could have a mix of number and text fields using different widgets. (The Unique Values widget may be of interest).

I haven't tried it, but you might be able to use field name aliases bases in user-defined variables, which you could edit in QField when in the field.

P.S. You have received down votes for your question. I suspect this is because the question appears poorly researched.

Answer (score 0):

Qfield allows you to edit feature layers created in QGIS desktop by importing your project in QField. It does not allow you to create new feature layers/shapefiles but only edit and save edits to existing feature layers (created in QGIS desktop).